# Linear approximation with two variables

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

The problem I have is this:

Use suitable linear approximation to find the approximate values for given functions
at the points indicated:

$f(x, y) = xe^{y+x^2}$ at $(2.05, -3.92)$

I know how to do linear approximation with just one variable (take the derivative and such), but with two variables (and later on in the assignment, three variables) I'm a bit lost. Do I take partial derivatives and combine then somehow? Can someone guide me through a problem of this type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(x,y)$=$f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$. Then $L(x,y) \approx f(x,y)$. Consider $(x_0,y_0)=(2,-4)$. Then, \begin{equation}
L(x,y)=2+9(x-2)+2(y+4) \implies f(2.05,-3.92) \approx L(2.05, -3.92)=2.61 \end{equation}
Notice, from a calculator, $f(2.05,-3.92)=2.7192$

Comment: Where did you get $(x_0, y_0) = (2, -4)$? Are those just arbitrary values?

Comment: More or less. I wanted to work with nice numbers that were near where you wanted to approximate at. The further away you get, the less L will approximate f.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're taking $(2, -4)$ and plugging it in to both the partial x derivative and partial y, and that's where 9 and the second 2 coefficient come from. The first 2 comes from just plugging in $(2, -4)$ to the original equation. Is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: Thank you so much! I assume for a 3 variable linear approximation, the formula and process is the same, except with the addition of a $f_z(x_0, y_0, z_0)(z-z_0)$ ? @Sloan

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Denoting the partial derivatives by $f'_x$ and $f'_y$, the formula is:
$$f(x_0+h,y_0+k)=f(x_0,y_0)+f'_x(x_0,y_0)h+f'_y(x_0,y_0)k+o\bigl(\lVert(h,k)\rVert\bigr).$$

Comment: What is 'h', 'k', and 'o' in this formula?

Comment: The amount by which $x_0$ is changed, as in the one-variable formula, i.e. $h=x-x_0$. Similarly $k=y-y_0$.

Comment: I'm confused on where $o(||(h,k)||)$ comes from. Could you explain that part?

Comment: Oh! I forgot that. It comes from asymptotic analysis (cf. Landau notations). We say a function $f$ is *dominated* by a function $g$ at $0$, or that $f(x)=_0 o(g(x))\,$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0 $. Roughly, it means $f(x)$ is *much*  smaller than $g(x)$.